# About Inequality problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

let $$x>-3$$

$$x^2<9$$

And $x=10$, because $10>-3$

But $x=-2.9$, The inequality is true.$(-2.9)^2<9$

$$x^2=10^2>9$$

Why is this happening? Can you explain me?

Comment: You have seen that $x^2>9$ does not follow from $x>-3$.

Comment: $x>-3$ does *not* imply $x^2<9$. $-3<x<3$ does. It is true that $-3<-2.9<3$ but it is *not* true that $-3<10<3$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim $x>-3\Longrightarrow x^{2}<9$ is incorrect, since for example $x=10>-3$ but $x^{2}=100\nless9$. In fact, if $x>-3$ then $x^{2}$ can attain any non-negative value. You can easily see this by plotting

$$f:\left[-3,\infty\right)\to\left[0,\infty\right)$$
$$f\left(x\right)=x^{2}$$

Comment: But why $-2<x<-1$ we get $4>x^2>1$

Comment: True that $-2<x<-1$ implies $1<x^2<4$. So what is your confusion?

Answer (score 0):

you have $x>-3$,

let's create 2 new inequality:

$$-3<x<0, 0\le x$$

now square those inequality:$$0<x^2<9, 0\le x^2$$

now we can combain those 2 again:$$x^2\ge0$$